# How to fetch Messenger data to my own database?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-messenger

I want to fetch my Messenger data to my own database. I want to use that data for my own application. Is it possible? What is the appropriate procedure?

Comment: There is no API to access messenger data.